# [HTTP:101401]The url-pattern Coordinator in web application Department.war is mapped to multiple Servlets?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, weblogic

I need to disable HTTP method  `OPTIONS` . I  placed below configuration in web.xml . It works(does not allow OPTIONS method) in tomcat but tthrow below error while
deployment

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Restricted HTTP methods.</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

`[HTTP:101401]The url-pattern Coordinator in web application Department.war is mapped to multiple Servlets`

Is there a different configuration required for weblogic or is it known bug in weblogic ?

Comment: Also, please look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187839/weblogic-upgrade-to-12c-deployment-fails-because-url-mapped-to-multiple-servlet

Comment: @Exception_al Actually i have already looked at second link. I am already using 12.2.1 . First link is irrelevant for this question

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this error in WL 12.2.1.3.0 and solved by removing the maven dependencies below:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```