# Weblogic 12.2.1 RegistrationService_V10 in web application war is mapped to multiple Servlets

Tags: weblogic, webservice-client, servlet-3.0

I am using Weblogic 12.2.1 and I added a JAX-WS client. It runs perfectly when run in eclipse but if I try to deploy the war file through the admin console I get:
The url-pattern RegistrationService_V10 in web application webApp.war is mapped to multiple Servlets. The only place I could find a reference to that is the the com.oracle.webservices.wls.wls-soap-stack-impl package in a class called RegistrationServiceV10 which is annotaited as a webservice to RegistrationService_V10 but that is the only place I could find a reference to it, not mapped in my web.xml so where is the multiple servlet mapping coming from.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked some time ago, but I had the same problem, and reading the question lead me to the answer, so here's what worked for me:

I had the same problem, did I text search on every single file in the repository for the text 'RegistrationService_V10' (and 'RegistrationService_V11', as I got that as an issue too), but it wasn't present.

The problem was the presence of multiple weblogic jar files. I was using maven to copy my dependencies into the weblogic domain lib folder, but because the code was depending on weblogic it was also copying a whole host of weblogic jar files as well. This resulted in multiple copies of the same files in my weblogic application classpath (the server's own weblogic files and my imported files). Thus there was an issue with code trying to register the same service with the same name more than once.

The solution is to make sure there is only one copy of the weblogic jar files available to weblogic (which is a part of weblogic; you shouldn't be copying any in).

Hope this helps you or somebody else with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing similar issue when uploading my war files to WebLogic server.

After scouring the internet for answers, I've stumbled this question [mapped to multiple servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187839/weblogic-upgrade-to-12c-deployment-fails-because-url-mapped-to-multiple-servlet) which led me to [OpenAM weblogic bugtracker](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/OPENAM-7947/OPENAM-7947.html)

> Workaround is to disable annotation processing by either:
>
> - starting WebLogic with -Dweblogic.servlet.DIDisabled=true parameter
>
> or
>
> - setting metadata-complete attribute to true in web.xml

```
<web-app metadata-complete="true" id="WebApp_ID" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
```

By putting `metadata-complete` on my web.xml, fixes the problem for me.

Comment: In my case, after adding `metadata-complete="true"`, application ignored `<context-param>` values.